# Bash script to execute a single command over multiple inputs one by one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a linux based command named as `x2goterminate-session` followed by username
e.g

```
x2goterminate-session john
```

But there are numerous user sessions that I want to terminate in a single go.

```
slpusrs=`x2golistsessions_root | grep '|S|' | cut -d "|" -f 2`
```

Above variable `slpusrs` finds the list of sleeping users and stores them in the slpusrs variable.

Now I want to execute x2goterminate-session command one by one on the list of users, so that all sleeping users are terminated in a single go instead of typing the command followed by user one by one.

```
command=x2goterminate-session
for i in "${slpusrs[@]}"; do
"$command" "$i"
done
```

But It isnt working. Please help

Comment: Does your command allow multiple usernames, i.e. `x2goterminate-session bill john steve sue` ?

Comment: @muhammadowaisKhaleeq : You reference `slpusrs` as array, but you set it as scalar. To set an array variable, you need `slpusrs=( $(....)  )`

Answer (score 2):

`slpusrs` is a string, not an array. Use

```
for i in $slpusrs; do
    "$command" $i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating with Bash, use `xargs` to run your command for each user.

```sh
x2golistsessions_root |
  grep '|S|' |
    cut -d "|" -f 2 |
      xargs -n1 x2goterminate-session
```

Comment: Thanks!! This worked for me.. Can u please tell that -n1 means only one argument for the command?

Comment: `xargs` defaults to passing as much arguments as it fiits to a single command call. But since your command may accept only one argument, `-n1` tells `xargs` to pass one argument at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If `x2goterminate-session` realls can work only on  one user at a time, you can do a

```
for user in $(x2golistsessions_root | grep '|S|' | cut -d "|" -f 2)
do
  echo "Murdering unser $user ..."
  x2goterminate-session "$user"
done
```

No need to introduce a separate variable, unless you need the list of users later on again.